# How to email Modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm fairly new to asp .net MVC, I've got a modal wish accepts a username, email address, comments, and also has a submit button. I'm looking create the submit functionality such that when it's pressed it'll send an email.

I've had passed experience sending emails in c# no problem, the troubles I'm having is linking the two together.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4>Contact Tech Site</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact-name" placeholder="Full Name">

            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="contact-email" placeholder="you@example.com">

            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="contact-msg" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
            <div class="col-lg-10">

              <textarea class="form-control" rows="8"></textarea>

            </div>

          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Email Code

```
var SMTP_USERNAME = User.EmailUsername;
var SMTP_PASSWORD = EncryptionHelper.Decrypt(User.EmailPassword);
Mail.Subject = Subject;
Mail.Body = EmailText;
foreach (var to in SelectedUsers)
{
    foreach (var contactMethod in to.ContactMethods.Where(x => x.Primary && x.Channel == ContactMethod.Channels.Email))
    {
        Mail.To.Add(contactMethod.Value);
    }
 }

 Mail.From = new MailAddress(SMTP_USERNAME, User.FullName());

 //Server
 var HOST = unitOfWork.SettingRepository.GetString(KnownKeys.SMTPServer);

 //Port
 var PORT = int.Parse(unitOfWork.SettingRepository.GetString(KnownKeys.SMTPPort));


 // Create an SMTP client with the specified host name and port.
 var emailSent = false;
 using (SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(HOST, PORT))
 {
     // Create a network credential with your SMTP user name and password.
     client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(SMTP_USERNAME, SMTP_PASSWORD);

     // Use SSL when accessing Amazon SES. The SMTP session will begin on an unencrypted connection, and then 
     // the client will issue a STARTTLS command to upgrade to an encrypted connection using SSL.
     client.EnableSsl = true;


     // Send the email. 
     try
     {
         client.Send(Mail);
         emailSent = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Error message: " + ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: please explain a bit more

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem with my solution?

Comment: Hi @ramiramilu I definitely liked your approach, sorry I haven't got to trying it out more indepth. When I did, the styling was completely off (using copy and paste).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a model -

```
public class EmailViewModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

And then create your controller -

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult GetEmailForm()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitEmail(EmailViewModel model)
    {
        var result = SendEamil(model);
        return View();
    }

    private bool SendEamil(EmailViewModel model)
    {
        // Use model and send email with your code.
        return true;
    }
}
```

Basically `GetEmailForm` action will return you a view with form -

```
@model MvcApplication1.Controllers.EmailViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "GetEmailForm";
}

<h2>GetEmailForm</h2>

<link href="../../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />


@using (Html.BeginForm("SubmitEmail", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
   <div id="contact">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <form class="form-horizontal">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4>Contact Tech Site</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Username, new { @placeholder = "Full Name"})
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @placeholder = "you@example.com"})
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contact-msg" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message:</label>
                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comments, new { @placeholder = "Comments"})
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Send</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

When you enter data and click on submit, it will post the viewmodel with data to `SubmitEmail` action of same controller.

Output of the page is as shown below, sorry for styles, i have no time so removed some of the styles.

[image]

When you enter data and click on submit, you get data as shown below -

[image]

Once you have the data, you can use that in your private method `SendEmail` (which will have your code) to send email.

Comment: There's a spelling mistake in the line `private bool SendEamil(EmailViewModel model)`...pointing it out in case the OP does a cut-n-paste without noticing it.

Comment: Hi @ramiramilu, When using this approach it made the modal appear very weird. http://snag.gy/XiBYZ.jpg and it was no longer a popup. It brought me to a new view.

Comment: @Master You should be able to take care of styling, my solution will give you a working form, but styling i think you should be able to take care of it.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to make it appear as a popup? Styling I think I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dd410596(v=vs.100).aspx) site for information on how to create a form, it will get submitted when the user presses the submit button. Back in yoru controller add a second version of your method with the HttpPost attribute and give it a parameter instance of your model, MVC will take care of the mapping for you. See [BUILDING ASP.NET MVC FORMS WITH RAZOR](http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2012/01/20/building-asp-net-mvc-forms-with-razor/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Call a action method From your Email Controller thru a ajax call.From the below Code  Snippet you will get an idea how to do it.

```
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function () { //Ur Button

      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
          url: "/EmailController/SendEmailAction",
          data: "{Email:" + $("#contact-email").val() +"}", // Reading from extboxes and Converting to JSON for Post to EmailController Action
          contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(result) {
       //alert message
           //Close the Modal
        }
        });

        });
```

And In C# level in youecontroller

```
public JsonResult _SendEmail(EmailViewModel model)
{
     //Here your code to send Email

}
```

I hope now you will get an idea how to go about it.
I think you do not require a form and submit button to send an email from a bootstrap modal.